# Code snippet issue about union in C

Tags: c, unions

I came across this C code snippet somewhere:

```
#include <stdio.h>

union {
    struct {
        unsigned char c1:3;
        unsigned char c2:3;
        unsigned char c3:2;
    } s;
    unsigned char c;
} u;

int main()
{
    u.c = 100;
    printf("%d %d %d\n", u.s.c1, u.s.c2, u.s.c3);

    return 0;
}
```

1. If you change the value in the line of `u.c = 100`, the output will be different, how does this happen?
2. If I assign it to a big integer like 1000, there will be warning message (I'm using flycheck in Emacs):

   ```
   implicit conversion from `int' to `unsigned char' changes value from 1000 to 232,
   ```

   What is 232?

Comment: You need to read a C tutorial to understand about the char data type, structs, bit-fields and unions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. All of the members of a union occupy the same location in memory.  `u.c` and `u.s` have the same address, so changing `u.c` will also change `u.s`.  Normally, you use a union when you want to:

   - have a value of either one type or of another type but either don't know which type until runtime or the type changes at runtime,
   - write a value to a variable of type A but read the same value from a different type,
   - do conversions between types.
2. 1000 % 256 = 232.  1000 doesn't fit in an unsigned char because an unsigned char is only 8 bits and 1000 is a 10 bit number.  Only the bottom 8 bits, which by themselves represent the number 232, survive.